# Создание своей комбинации клавиш Visual Studio

Tags: xml, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Оцифровываю книжку в формат FB2, постоянно приходится выделять текст тегами `<emphasis>` и `<code>`. Давно уже сделал xml фрагмент по добавлению  выше описанных тегов.

Как назначить на фрагмент комбинацию клавиш?

Хочу получить для ускорения работы: выделить текст-> комбинация -> слева справа от текста добавились теги.

---

добавлено 13.11.2012 21:12

правильное английское название xml фрагментов -- "snippets", так что интересует как на сниппет повесить комбинацию клавиш

Answer (score 0, accepted):

по крайней мере в VS2012 на snippets нельзя повесить комбинации клавиш, реализовал всё через макросы и регулярки...